# Extra argument 'error' in call - Unable to build my Xcode project

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, nsjsonserialization

```
import Foundation

class NetworkOperation {

    lazy var config: NSURLSessionConfiguration =     NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    lazy var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: self.config)
    let queryURL: NSURL

    typealias JSONDictionaryCompletion = ([String: AnyObject]? -> Void)

    init(url: NSURL) {
        self.queryURL = url
    }

    func downloadJSONFromURL(completion: JSONDictionaryCompletion) {

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: queryURL)
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (let data, let response, let error) in
```

*// 1. Check HTTP response for successful GET request*

```
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                case 200:
```

*// 2. Create JSON object with data*

```
                    let jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
                    completion(jsonDictionary)
                default:
                    print("GET request not successful. HTTP status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: Not a valid HTTP response")
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

*In the 'Create JSON object with data' step, I keep receiving the "extra argument 'error' in call". What is happening? I am unable to find documentation to help me further in this.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*// 1. Check HTTP response for successful GET request*

```
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                case 200:
```

*// 2. Create JSON object with data*

```
                    let jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String: AnyObject]
                    completion(jsonDictionary)
                default:
                    println("GET request not successful. HTTP status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                }
            } else {
                println("Error: Not a valid HTTP response")
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

*Finally figured it out! Thank you for your input everyone!*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this way.

```
do{
        var jsonDictionary  = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        //completion(jsonDictionary)
    }catch{
       // report error
    }
```

Comment: I haven't used 'do'/'catch' yet. This reminds me of Python's 'try'/'except'. I am unsure how to execute this properly in Swift, could you direct me to more documentation or better explain it? Thank you!

Comment: Also, do I remove the entire 'if let' statement and ad the 'do'/'catch'? Or do I just remove everything under '// 2.'? Thank you!

Comment: every thing of "case 200:" put into try block

Comment: unfortunately that didn't fix it. I managed to clear that error, but now I am receiving another about 'completion(jsonDictionary)' saying it Cannot invoke 'completion' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?)'

Comment: in "completion: JSONDictionaryCompletion" the argument of completion is JSONDictionaryCompletion but u are trying to pass argument as Anyobject which makes mismatch. so you need to customize the "jsonDictionary" to JSONDictionaryCompletion.

note: click on red error mark, it will show possible solution and pressed enter/ write what it says.

Answer (score 0):

at the top of step 2: creating json....

add this line:

```
var err: NSError?
```

Comment: This didn't work. Thank you for your input, it is appreciated.